# jquery plugin football on post back

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, gridview

i am using jquery football plugin for make asp.net gridview responsive problem is that when my page is post back jquery code not working and its also lost CSS of gridview code is

```
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-footable/0.1.0/js/footable.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('[id*=GridView1]').footable();
        });
    </script>
```

my page is simple no update panel just a simple page without master page.